# How to get LOCALE_SNAME using JScript in TestComplete?

Tags: locale, jscript, testcomplete

Using JScript in TestComplete, how do I retrieve the locale name?

1. Should I use `GetLocaleInfo` or `GetLocaleInfoEx`?
2. It looks like the `LOCALE_SNAME` constant is not defined in TestComplete. What value should I pass instead?

I tried this code:

```js
function GetTimeSettings()
{
  var rrr = Win32API.GetUserDefaultLCID();
  LOCALE_SNAME = rrr;
  Log.Message("Locale Name: " + GetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNAME));
}
```

but it throws the "Object expected" error.

Comment: can you provide code that shows your problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`aqEnvironment.GetLocaleInfo`](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55442/), or just `GetLocaleInfo` for short. It's a wrapper for the Windows API function [`GetLocaleInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101.aspx).
2. The `LOCALE_SNAME` constant isn't defined in TestComplete; you need to define it manually:

   ```js
   var LOCALE_SNAME = 0x0000005c;
   Log.Message(GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNAME));
   ```